# How i can change the selected background color input html/js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make Rock,Paper,Scissors game but i wanted to make when the player select (For Example Rock) and he win's the Input(Rock) background color changes but I'm having a hard time doing since I'm still learning js

html :

```
<div id="buttonsInput" class="m-4">
            <input type="image" width="150px" height="150px" src="photo's/r.png" name="rock" class="border border-light rounded-circle rock d-inline m-2" id="Rock">
            <input type="image" width="150px" height="150px" src="photo's/p.png" name="paper" class="border border-light rounded-circle paper d-inline m-2" id="Paper">
            <input type="image" width="150px" height="150px" src="photo's/s.png" name="scissors" class="border border-light rounded-circle scissors d-inline m-2" id="Scissors">
        </div>
```

js :

```
function win(userChoice, pcChoice){
    userScore++;
    if(userScore > 5 ){
    userScore = 0;
    pcScore = 0;
    alert("You WIN !");
    location.reload()
    }
    userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
    pcScore_span.innerHTML = pcScore;
    const player = "Player".fontsize(4).fontcolor("#dc3545").sup();
    const PC = "PC".fontsize(4).fontcolor("#dc3545").sup();
    const win = "Win!".fontcolor("#28a745")
    result_div.innerHTML = userChoice + player + " Beats "+ pcChoice + PC +" "+ " You "+ win;
}
```

here is GitHub :
https://github.com/AppleGamer77/rockpaperscissors

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more. Of what element's background you want to be changed.Also comment the location.reaload() line until you are done creating your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background colour of the div can be changed in these 2 steps:

**Step 1: Update CSS**

Define these 3 CSS classes for 3 results(winner, looser, draw):

File name:  **rps_style.css**  (Add the following new classes to the file)

```
.winner {
    background-color: #b6eac8;
}

.looser {
    background-color: #fa6000;
}

.draw {
    background-color: #ddbbaa;
}
```

---

**Step 2: Update Javascript**

Update Javascript functions (win, loose, draw) to set the appropriate css class to the input div

File name:  **java.js**

```
function win(userChoice, pcChoice){
    //  existing code 

    // Add the following lines the end of the function
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("buttonsInput")
    if (myDiv.className.indexOf("winner") <= 0) {
        myDiv.className = "m-4 winner";
    }
    
}

function loses(userChoice, pcChoice){

    // existing code 

    // Add the following lines the end of the function
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("buttonsInput")
    if (myDiv.className.indexOf("looser") <= 0) {
        myDiv.className = "m-4 looser";
    }
        
}

function draw(userChoice, pcChoice){

    // existing code 

    // Add the following lines the end of the function
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("buttonsInput")
    if (myDiv.className.indexOf("draw") <= 0) {
        myDiv.className = "m-4 draw";
    }
    
}
```

---

---

**Output:**

**1. Win:**

[image]

---

**2. Loose:**

[image]

---

**3. Draw:**

[image]

---

**More information:** https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_html_classname.asp

Comment: Very good i liked the idea but i meant the selected bacground color not the actual background , like if the player selected rock and it's a win the rock button it self changes the background color but i like your idea .


this :

.rock:focus{
    background-color: rgb(68, 39, 39);
}